# Intellij, jlink doesn't exist

Tags: java, android, windows, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

So, i just updated to the newest at this moment intellij (2023.3.4). According to an error, i just lost my Jlink. How i suppossed to get it back? Using Java 17.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\ancen\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > jlink executable C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.4\jbr\bin\jlink.exe does not exist.

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
```

Tried to search on stackoverflow. Founded that Linux user also doesn't have Jlink, and it setted up JAVA_HOME with other Java version. I tried this, but got nothing

Comment: Is it a Gradle project? You may download some JDK for developers by using Project Structure: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2023.3/project-settings-and-structure.html#project-sdk . Also the Gradle JVM should be changed to the new one: Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that all other project are working fine. So, i just created a new project in intellij and then copied and pasted all dependecies/code/xml files/manifest into a new created project. And my code runs. I'm clearly don't know how it works, but it works.

Comment: I can't accept my own answer because it on cooldown for 2 days.